# TypeError: Argument 2 must be Tuple or List

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, mariadb

I have built a GUI using TKinter. There I want to output the stored data and change them individually.
Using the UPDATE command, I want to update the data in the table.
I use MariaDB as database.

I'm getting this error:

> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Zlatan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Zlatan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\polymer\tssr.py", line 296, in update
>     c.execute("""UPDATE tssr SET TypeError: Argument 2 must be Tuple or List!
> ```

Here is the complete function:

```
# create update function 
def update():
# connect to database
conn = mariadb.connect(
    user="root",
    password="pass",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=3306,
    database="polymer"
)

# create cursor
c = conn.cursor()

record_id = select_box.get()

c.execute("""UPDATE tssr SET
    Order_name = :order_name,
    Operator_name = :operator_name,
    Sample = :sample,
    Strain = :strain

    WHERE ID = :ID""",
          {
              'order_name': Order_name_editor.get(),
              'operator_name': Operator_name_editor.get(),
              'sample': Sample_editor.get(),
              'strain': Strain_editor.get(),
              'ID': record_id
          })

# commit changes
conn.commit()
# close connection
conn.close()
```

Any suggestions where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, the 2nd argument of `execute()` should be a `list` or a `tuple`, while you're using a `dict`. Try this:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE tssr SET
    Order_name = %s,
    Operator_name = %s,
    Sample = %s,
    Strain = %s
    WHERE ID = %s""",
          (
              Order_name_editor.get(),
              Operator_name_editor.get(),
              Sample_editor.get(),
              Strain_editor.get(),
              record_id
          )
    )
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you!

Comment: Great, make sure to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB Connector/Python doesn't support named style parameters as listed in PEP-249. The default paramstyle is **qmark**:

```
>>> mariadb.paramstyle
'qmark'
```

However it is possible also to use **format** or **pyformat** paramstyles (with the limitation that they can't be mixed):

```
cursor.execute("select ?,?", ("This is paramstyle", "qmark"));
cursor.execute("select %s,%s", ("This is paramstyle", "format"));
cursor.execute("select %(val1)s,%(val2)s", { "val1" : "This is paramstyle", "val2" : "pyformat"});
```